# Multiple Conditions using AND and Wildcards in WHERE clause

Tags: javascript, sql, db2, sql-like, presto

I have a screen that has has 3 input fileds that are used to capture search criteria from the user. None of them are mandatory and I'm using the input values as paramaters in my `SQL WHERE` clause. Here is an example

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4,  
FROM table LEFT JOIN otherTable on tableID = otherTableID
WHERE col1 like :d1 and col2 like :d2 and col3 like :d3
```

The user data is captured from the browser like

```
var inputField1= "%" + jQ.trim(jQ(".someclass").val()) + "%";
var inputField2= "%" + jQ.trim(jQ(".someclass").val()) + "%";
var inputField3= "%" + jQ.trim(jQ(".someclass").val()) + "%";
```

and then used in a `Presto.ExecuteSql` object

```
    Presto.ExecuteSql(
{
    name: "SQL_Query",
    params:
    {
        'd1': inputField1,
        "d2": inputField2,
        "d3": inputField3,
        "d4": inputField4,
    },
```

When the user enters in data in all three fields then the query returns the correct amount of records, however when they only enter in data in one input field the amount of records returned is not correct. How do I modify the `WHERE` clause to always return the correct amount of records.

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass `null` parameters with boolean logic:

```
where (:d1 is null or col1 like :d1)
  and (:d2 is null or col2 like :d2)
  and (:d3 is null or col3 like :d3)
```